# Are azure sites deployed transitionally?

Tags: azure, azure-deployment, azure-web-app-service

when deploying azure websites to a farm of lets say 10 instances, how is the deployment of the new version propagated?

is there a time where different users could hit diffident version of the site based on where the load balancer sends them? or does azure spin up a whole new set and does an ip swap when they are all ready?

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking azure websites a lot more like "Windows Azure Web Role" which is not true. With Windows Azure Website your website (shared) is sharing resources without hundreds of other website so there is not such ip swap, and update domains etc.

Websites are stored on a content share which is accessible from all the "web servers" in the farm so there is no replication or anything like that required. So with shared and reserved website the update will be instant for all instances. With larger package update it may take some time for file system change notification however once the file system update notification is available all the instances will pickup the updated code instantly.

With Windows Azure website, the content is located at "content share" and all instances are getting data from there so there is never a chance where multiple instances  have different version of data.

Comment: 1. Azure websites don't need to be very simple static websites. 2. you can have a machine dedicated to your site, if i publish a big update, 200mb update, for a site that takes 2 minutes to spin up, i'm trying to see what happens behind the scene.

Comment: "RESERVED INSTANCE SIZE
Use additional options for scale up by specifying the size of the virtual machines. By changing this setting from small to medium or large, the web site will run in a compute instance of corresponding size with access to associated resources for each size."

Comment: from ScottGu's blog "You can then optionally upgrade your sites to run in a “reserved mode” that isolates them so that you are the only customer within a virtual machine" http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/06/07/meet-the-new-windows-azure.aspx

Comment: There is some misunderstanding about what is "Windows Azure Websites" and what is "Windows Azure Virtual Machine". You are talking about "Windows Azure Virtual Machine" and quoting "websites" that's why there is big disconnect. You need to reference that you are talking about "Windows Azure Virtual Machines".

Comment: I'm talking about reserved azure websites.

Comment: Shared web sites can have multiple instances also.  The question is still unanswered: how does deployment of a web site work when there are multiple instances?

Comment: This statement is NOT accurate: 'Reserve website actually becomes a "Windows Azure Virtual Machine" and that changes the whole dynamics'

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am writing a new blog to explain more on this regard.